# Where is UserControl<TViewModel> in catel 5.12

Tags: user-controls, catel

I've some nested UserControls on an MVVM/WPF project using .NET 6.0 and Catel 5.12.22
Google led me to this, all be it an old article https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129920/Catel-Part-3-of-n-The-MVVM-Framework#mapping

I can't find the UserControl anymore in the Catel 5.12

Lots of dead links to old documentation currently, so please advise where I can find this, or how it works now.

Jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserControl still exists in Catel.

Here is the [full documentation](https://docs.catelproject.com/5.x/catel-mvvm/views/xaml/usercontrol/).

To use it in xaml, use this code:

```
<catel:UserControl x:Class="Catel.Views.MyControl"
                   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                   xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com">
    
    <!-- For the sake of simplicity, content is left out -->
    
</catel:UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the current documentation. As I expected it shows that the example found is outdated. With this I can move forward